# Calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues? No idea how to solve this without using a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\1&4&3\\3&2&4\end{bmatrix},$$
how can I calculate the eigenvalues?
When I try the traditional way of calculating the determinant of  $A- λI_3$, I end up with this polynomial: $p_A(λ)=-λ^3+8λ^2-3λ-15$.
Which has no integer solutions?

My hint was given as follows:

To find the roots of the characteristic polynomial of this matrix, you may wish to start with the assumption that one of these roots is an integer. You can then narrow down the possibilities for the value of this root $z_0$ based on what the coefficients of $p_A (t)$ are (and also based on the fact that $t − z_0$ should divide $p_A (t)$).

I'm unsure how to solve this problem given the tools for a year $1$ linear algebra class.

Comment: You are right. The given matrix does not have integer eigenvalues. Either the hint is wrong or the matrix is wrong.

Comment: If you replace the $0$ in your matrix by a $9$ you can go ahead as suggested.